# R: Draw arrows in ggplot2 based on loop

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, vegan, arrows

I have a dataset as follows:

```
i <- data.scores
i
               NMDS1         NMDS2
Plot_1_O  -0.1716069847  -1.177471624
Plot_2_O  -0.2452065424  -0.978276228
Plot_3_O   0.3885298355  -0.578810975
   ...         ...            ...
Plot_64_O  0.7976712787  -0.187241724
Plot_1_N  -0.4044221768  -0.239157686
Plot_2_N   0.2539782304   0.197509348
Plot_3_N   0.3163483600  -0.130876763
   ...         ...            ...
Plot_64_N  0.6346501475   0.265873211
```

As you (may or may not) see, it's vegetational plot-data on 64 different plots, taken at several points in time (hence the "O"/"N" for "Old" and "New"). I've ran an NMDS via `vegan`'s `metaMDS()` and got a plot showing my results. I've also calculated a fit via `env_fit()` and relevant environmental data. The finished plot is fine, but I wanted to add arrows between the pairs of old and new survey data. I used a loop to do so:

```
for (j in 1:64){   
  k <- j+64
 arrows(data.scores$NMDS1[j], data.scores$NMDS2[j],
 data.scores$NMDS1[k], data.scores$NMDS2[k], length = 0.1, lwd=2)
}
```

The resulting plot looks like this: [NMDS-Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUFLR.jpg)
The black symbols show the old plots, the red symbols the new ones respectively.
For better aesthetics I re-drew the plot in `ggplot2`, and everything worked perfectly fine, until I had to draw those arrows again. I cannot use a loop within the ggplot2-command, and I do not know how draw all of those arrows at once. I tried something like this:

```
 geom_segment(data=i, aes(x=i$NMDS1[1:64], xend=i$NMDS1[65:128],
 y=i$NMDS2[1:64], yend=i$NMDS2[65:128]), 
 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")), colour="red",
 inherit.aes=FALSE, lwd=2)
```

but it does not draw any arrows at all, not even a single one. Removing the column-specification does not help either, and I doubt I would get all the respective arrows at once. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you provide a full reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Based on my last line of code where I tried to draw the arrows `geom_segment(data=i, aes(x=i$NMDS1[1:64], xend=i$NMDS1[65:128], y=i$NMDS2[1:64], yend=i$NMDS2[65:128]), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")), colour="red", inherit.aes=FALSE, lwd=2)` I saved the plot as an object called "Plot_Final" and tried this:

```
for (j in 1:64){ #j=1
  k <- j+64
  Plot_Final <- Plot_Final + geom_segment(data=i, x=i$NMDS1[j], xend=i$NMDS1[k], y=i$NMDS2[j], yend=i$NMDS2[k], arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")), colour="black", inherit.aes=FALSE, lwd=0.1)
}
```

By removing the `aes()`-argument I finally got my arrows pointing out the plot-pairs within my `ggplot2`-plot. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Nies that you find a solution, but did you try `geom_path` with argument `group`  that tells which of the point belong to the same group? This looks like **ggplot2** version of **vegan** `ordiarrows`  function that is provided for your task in conventional graphics. Please don't forget to add `+ coord.fixed()`: you *must* use equal aspect ratio in ordinatin plots.

Comment: I tried using `geom_path()` to show the connections, but it drew lines between different old plots, too. I don't know how to avoid drawing connections within old and new plot-data, and I already programmed the loop for the "standard" plotting in R, so it was convenient to find a way to implement it into `ggplot2`. Maybe if I'd add more information for the `group`-argument to work... But thanks for your tip!

Comment: It seems that `group` should be unique for each pair of old and  new plots -- something like `gl(2, 64)`. The following worked with **vegan** example, and draws arrows like `ordiarrows`  or  `ordixyplot` in **vegan**: `data(pyrifos); example(pyrifos); mod <- metaMDS(pyrifos, dist="manhattan"); sco <- as.data.frame(scores(mod))` for setup and then for the plot: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(sco) + geom_point(data=sco, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2, colour=dose)) + geom_path(data=sco, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2, group=ditch, colour=dose), arrow=arrow()) + coord_fixed()`.  Sorry for the layout.